# Validate a Column in DataGridView using File.ReadAllLines?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, contains, datagridviewcolumn

I am doing a validation on a certain column called "KPI".
What I'm doing is making a .txt file that will be used for validation of the column.

### The .txt file looks like this.

---

[image]

---

As you can see in the notepad, it has 4 values.

1. Revenue
2. Sales Volume
3. Gross Con
4. Brand Con

Anything other than that, the validation would say, "is NOT valid".

### Here is the code I used to get the values from the .txt file

---

```
        List<string> fields = new List<string>();

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"\\SMITSHOME01\Home_Folder_1$\vhernandez\My Documents\Visual Studio 2013\validate.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            fields.Add(lines[i]);

        }
```

But I am not very good in looping so I'm asking if someone could help me do it.
For now, what I'm doing is this.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount; i++)
            {

                //MessageBox.Show(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["KPI"].Value.ToString()); 
                if (dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["KPI"].Value.ToString().Contains(fields[i]))
                {
                    //sb.AppendLine(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["KPI"].Value.ToString() + " is Valid.");
                }

                else if (dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["KPI"].Value.ToString() == null || dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["KPI"].Value.ToString() == "" || dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["KPI"].Value.ToString() == "KPI" || dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["KPI"].Value.ToString() == "Category")
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Row not decimal:" + " [ " + dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() + "] in column "  + dataGridView.Columns[h].Name);
                    sb.AppendLine(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["KPI"].Value.ToString() + " is **NOT** Valid.");
                }
            }
```

I am using `.Contains()` for the validation but I always get `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because of my inefficiency with `for` loops.

I want to dynamically add `fields[]` in the if `.Contains()` or somehow reference it, can someone help me?

### Here's the picture of the form for reference:

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your check in `if` condition should be other way around :

```
if(fields.Contains(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["KPI"].Value.ToString()))
```

Comment: @ShanCoralde : np. on additional note : can't you bind your grid with strongly typed list or something of that sort ? that would make your much code cleaner.

Comment: Care to explain? I'm fairly new to C# and on a beginner level.

Comment: Sure. I believe you binding gridView to some data source, right ? what is the type of that source ? For example if you reading say from SQL using ado.net, you can better populate some collection (say List<Student>) and bind that to gridView. That will help you to make use of beautiful linq features rather than having loops and all.

Comment: The data source is from an excel file I've imported to the `DataGridView`.